# Replace Dictionary values C#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have two dictionaries say

```
Dictionary<int,string> DictA=new Dictionary<int,string>();
DictA.Add(1,"A");
DictA.Add(2,"B");
DictA.Add(3,"C");
DictA.Add(4,"D");
Dictionary<string,string> DictB=new Dictionary<string,string>();
DictB.Add("A","A1");
DictB.Add("C","C1");
DictB.Add("D","D1");
```

Now I need a resultant dictionary as follows

- <1,"A1">
- <2,"B"> //Since B is missing in Second Dictionary it should
  retain its old value
- <3,"C1">
- <4,"D1">

I am not happy with the iterator code I wrote for this using `foreach`, but I am certain that there is very short and cleaner way to do this using Lambda Expressions. I am very new to them and finding them difficult to understand.

Can someone explain a good resource to learn them and use efficiently with an example.

Comment: "I am not happy with the iterator code I wrote" you should show us the code. It might be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `LINQ`.Basically just check if the second dictionary contains the value of first dictionary as `Key`, if it does get the value from second dictionary, if it doesn't get the value from the first dictionary:

```
DictA
.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int,string>(x.Key, 
                                          DictB.ContainsKey(x.Value) 
                                          ? DictB[x.Value] 
                                          : x.Value)
.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: that was in my clipboard!

Comment: The `Select()` then `ToDictionary()` call is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

you can use [ToDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.95).aspx) to generate the dictionary the way you want.

```
var result = DictA.ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => DictB.ContainsKey(a.Value) ? DictB[a.Value] : a.Value);

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key + ", " + item.Value);
}
```

and here is the result

> 1, A1
>   2, B
>   3, C1
>   4, D1

and if you want to do it inplace you can modify `DictA`

```
foreach (var key in DictA.Keys.ToList())
{
   DictA[key] = DictB.ContainsKey(DictA[key]) ? DictB[DictA[key]] : DictA[key];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simple:

```
var result =
    DictA
        .ToDictionary(
            a => a.Key,
            a => DictB.ContainsKey(a.Value)
                ? DictB[a.Value]
                : a.Value);
```

I get this result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to do it `inplace`

```
DictA.ToList().ForEach(kv =>
{
    if (DictB.ContainsKey(kv.Value))
        DictA[kv.Key] = DictB[kv.Value];
});
```

Comment: OP does not want this inplace, "Now I need a resultant dictionary as follows"

Comment: "Now I need a resultant dictionary as follows", and this is in the content. who should we trust? title or content? :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do what you want:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey,TValue> Extend<TKey,TValue>( params Dictionary<TKey,TValue>[] sources )
{
  return Extend<TKey,TValue>( null , sources ) ;
}

public static Dictionary<TKey,TValue> Extend<TKey,TValue>( IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer , params Dictionary<TKey,TValue>[] sources )
{
  var result = new Dictionary<TKey,TValue>( comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default ) ;

  foreach( var src in sources )
  {
    if ( src == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("sources", "source dictionary may not be null");

    foreach( var item in src )
    {
      result[item.Key] = item.Value ;
    }
  }

  return result ;
}
```

Here's another way, using Linq:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey,TValue> Extend<TKey,TValue>( params Dictionary<TKey,TValue>[] sources )
{
  return Extend<TKey,TValue>( null , sources ) ;
}
public static Dictionary<TKey,TValue> Extend<TKey,TValue>( IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer , params Dictionary<TKey,TValue>[] sources )
{
  return sources
         .SelectMany( kvp => kvp )
         .GroupBy( kvp => kvp.Key , kvp => kvp.Value , comparer )
         .ToDictionary( grp => grp.Key , grp => grp.Last() , comparer )
         ;
}
```

But I'm willing to bet that the first, straightforward method will be faster.